# reading csv file and rearanging data

Tags: r

Hi I have a multiple csv files in folder and each file consists of data in below format need to append all files in single df
[image: cust_details]

```
Name:   John    Los Angeles CA              
col1                   col2             col3                        col4    
12/1/14 1:00 AM 13  12/5/14 1:00 AM  19     12/7/14 1:00 AM   32    12/11/14 1:00 AM    13
12/2/14 1:00 AM 91  12/6/14 1:00 AM  20.9   12/8/14 1:00 AM   111.9     
                    12/7/14 1:00 AM  22.8   12/9/14 1:00 AM   22.8      
                    12/8/14 1:00 AM  24.7   12/10/14 1:00 AM  24.7      
                                            12/11/14 1:00 AM    0
```

i am trying to append every 2 columns one below the other as shown below
 i tried with `raw = read.csv("file1.csv",header = T,skip = 1)` and unable to further

```
Date           value    variable    Name    city     State   file_name
12/1/14 1:00 AM   13    col1       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/2/14 1:00 AM   91    col1       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/5/14 1:00 AM   19    col2       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/6/14 1:00 AM   20.9  col2       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/7/14 1:00 AM   22.8  col2       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/8/14 1:00 AM   24.7  col2       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/7/14 1:00 AM   32    col3       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/8/14 1:00 AM   111.9 col3       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/9/14 1:00 AM   22.8  col3       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/10/14 1:00 AM  24.7  col3       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/11/14 1:00 AM  0     col3       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
12/11/14 1:00 AM  13    col4       John  Los Angeles    CA    file
....
.... 
12/11/14 1:00 AM  33    col1       hayes  SD             CA   file_1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add part of data from one `csv` as part of question. The image in `XLS` doesnt help in recreating sample data.

Comment: I would read the data and then manipulate it rather than trying to read it in a certain way. I see the data is time dependant so you could order it by time and then variable ? (i dont know what you want to do with overlapping periods) that or I would define an extra column which would give the grouping according to the col number from variable so that col1 is 1, col2 is 1, col3 is 2, col4 is 2 and so on then group.

Comment: @Prost,Thanks intially i am trying to read data and manipulate i.e with df= read.csv("file1.csv",header = T,skip = 1)   & df1 =setNames(data.frame(stack(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)])[1], 
                        stack(df[c(FALSE, TRUE)])), 
             (select = c('Date', 'value', 'variable')))